# Java Script / Wordpress Gutenberg Block Plugin / cant add a second class to div

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

Maybe someone can help me with this strange behavior ...

I am writing on a "Wordpress Gutenberg Block" plugin and just want to give the first div a second class in the return function.

It works but not then it should.

I want get:

```
<div class="wp-block-womoblocks-katblock col-lg-4">
```

But i get always:

```
<div class="wp-block-womoblocks-katblock undefinedcol-lg-4">
```

Here is the code of the function:

```
save: function( props ) {

    var attributes = props.attributes;
    var colg4 = "col-lg-4";
    var colclass = props.className + colg4;
    return (
        el( 'div', { className: colclass },
        el( 'div', { className: 'col-lg-4' },
        el( 'div', { className: 'kat-post' },

        el( RichText.Content, {
            tagName: 'h2', value: attributes.title
        } ),
        attributes.mediaURL &&
            el( 'div', { className: 'kat-image' },
                el( 'img', { src: attributes.mediaURL } ),
            ),
            el( RichText.Content, {
                tagName: 'div', className: 'kat-ausz', value: attributes.instructions
            } ),
        )))
    );
},
```

I have tried several options but I always get this undefined before col-lg-4 and have no ideas on how to solve it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `var colg4 = "col-lg-4";` add a space like `var colg4 = "  col-lg-4";`

Comment: Thanks for the hint but now i have:
class="wp-block-womoblocks-katblock undefined test"

I dont kow where this undefined come from ... :-(

The Variable is defined and shown in the output ....

Thank you

Comment: Also when i simply do something like:
props.className = props.className+"test3"; 

I will get:
class="wp-block-womoblocks-katblock undefinedtest3"

I think there is something in the background in the Gutenberg Editor Code that i dont know ....

For the moment i use:
props.className = props.className+"1 test";

So i will get two classes (undefined1 and test) and can use the second.

Comment: please console.log the `props` value and share me the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the assignment of `colclass` because there is no need for `props.className`.

In `save` function of `registerBlockType` class is added automatically to the outermost element but in `edit` function you have to explicitly write it so mistakenly you are using same approach on both.

I also suggest you to use the more latest ES6 / ESNext syntax instead of ES5 because it's friendly to code in that, Gutenberg docs also have a toggle that shows you ESNext code.